# how to dynamically build watch task's targets?

Tags: gruntjs

using `gurunt syncall`, I want to dynamically sync every dir(and new dir created in the futrue) in project root except 'node_modules' dir  to another dir.

using `grunt watchall`, I want to watch those dirs, when there are some changes in a dir, I want to automaticlly run the corresponding sync task.

here is my project root's structure:

```
├── Gruntfile.js
├── addon1
│   └── a.toc
├── adon3
│   └── 3.toc
├── node_modules
│   ├── grunt
│   ├── grunt-contrib-watch
│   └── grunt-sync
└── package.json
```

the `grunt syncall` command is ok, here is the result:

```
➜  testsync  grunt syncall 
Running "config" task

Running "sync:addon1" (sync) task

Running "sync:adon3" (sync) task

Done, without errors.
```

but the `grunt watchall` not ok. **can you tell me why `watchall` tasks not work and how to fix it?**

I start the command, and change and save the file '3.toc' in dir 'adon3',  then grunt say:

```
➜  testsync  grunt watchall
Running "config" task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "adon3/3.toc" changed.
Running "sync:adon3" (sync) task
Verifying property sync.adon3 exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "sync.adon3" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({});

  var destdir = "/Users/morrxy/project/testdest/";

  // dynamic config sync and watch's targets for every dir except for node_modules
  grunt.registerTask('config', 'config sync and watch', function() {

    grunt.file.expand({filter: 'isDirectory'},
      ['*', '!node_modules']).forEach(function(dir) {

      // config sync's targets
      var sync = grunt.config.get('sync') || {};
      sync[dir] = {
        files: [{
          cwd: dir,
          src: '**',
          dest: destdir + dir
        }]
      };
      grunt.config.set('sync', sync);

      // config watch's target
      var watch = grunt.config.get('watch') || {};
      watch[dir] = {
        files: dir + '/**/*',

        // is next line has problem?

        // running 'grunt watchall'
        // when I change and save the file '3.toc' in dir 'adon3', terminal say:

        // >> File "adon3/3.toc" changed.
        // Running "sync:adon3" (sync) task
        // Verifying property sync.adon3 exists in config...ERROR
        // >> Unable to process task.
        // Warning: Required config property "sync.adon3" missing.

        // but why 'grunt syncall' can work?
        tasks: 'sync:' + dir
      };
      grunt.config.set('watch', watch);

    });

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sync');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('syncall', ['config', 'sync']);
  grunt.registerTask('watchall', ['config', 'watch']);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem. I add a github repo for this question. If you want test, you can clone it run it locally. https://github.com/morrxy/dynasync

The reason `watchall` can watch files changes but can't run the corresponding sync task is that when watch find files changed, the config for each sync is finnished running, so the config for that sync target is gone, we didn't save the running config any where. So to solve this problem, we could add the config task into the watch task before the sync task, like this `tasks: ['config_sync', 'sync:' + dir]`.

in new Gruntfile.js, I split the config task to two task, one for config watch, one for config sync, in the watch task, using the config sync task. Here is the new Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var destdir = "/media/data/projects/dynasync_dest/";

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sync');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // dynamic config sync's targets for every dir except for node_modules
  grunt.registerTask('config_sync', 'dynamically config sync', function() {

    grunt.file.expand({filter: 'isDirectory'},
      ['*', '!node_modules']).forEach(function(dir) {

      // config this dir's sync target
      var sync = grunt.config.get('sync') || {};
      sync[dir] = {
        files: [{
          cwd: dir,
          src: '**/*',
          dest: destdir + dir
        }]
      };
      grunt.config.set('sync', sync);

    });

  });

  // dynamic config watch's targets for every dir except for node_modules
  grunt.registerTask('config_watch', 'dynamically config watch', function() {

    grunt.file.expand({filter: 'isDirectory'},
      ['*', '!node_modules']).forEach(function(dir) {

      // config this dir's watch target
      var watch = grunt.config.get('watch') || {};
      watch[dir] = {
        files: dir + '/**/*',
        // this line solve the problem
        // when find file change, first dynamically config sync and then sync the dir
        tasks: ['config_sync', 'sync:' + dir]
      };
      grunt.config.set('watch', watch);

    });

  });

  grunt.registerTask('syncall', ['config_sync', 'sync']);
  grunt.registerTask('watchall', ['config_watch', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watchall']);

};
```

This time, when watch find file changes, it can run the corresponding sync task. like this

```
grunt watchall
Running "config_watch" task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "adon3/3.toc" changed.
Running "config_sync" task

Running "sync:adon3" (sync) task

Done, without errors.
Completed in 0.888s at Thu Apr 10 2014 14:01:26 GMT+0800 (CST) - Waiting...
```